# How to Convert Node JS Binary To iOS Nsdata

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift5

Following is the node js code to convert file to binary how do i read that file in ios thanks in advance

```
var file = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');
```

i have tried converting the binary file as below But its does not work.I send file as json to ios {"data":file} from node js

```
 NSData *data = [datafromServer valueForKey:@"data"];
```

datafromServer is the json sent from the node js server

Comment: It's a common misconception: not all data is convertible into UTF8. What is `datafromServer`? Isn't it already `NSData`?

Comment: datafromServer is an Nsdictionary in which the file is sent throught api but for some reson the file is getting corrpted @Larme

Comment: "i have Tried This But its does not work" - please explain what doesn't work. And what do you mean by "for some reson the file is getting corrpted"?

Comment: So i a reading a file in binary from Node Js as you can se the code i send the file throught a json as {"data":file} now on the ios side i read the json into the nsdata and then save it to document directory but the file is not save so my question is am i doing something wrong in converting the json ? to nsdata @koen

Comment: Don't add extra information in the comments, but edit your question instead. And please proofread your text before posting it. See also [ask].

Comment: can you help on this @koen ??

Comment: i am new to stack i will keep that in mind next time for sure how to ask question thanks